# How do I recover from Debian 10 crash after running apt --fix-broken install?

Tags: debian, crash, runlevel

Debian 10 crashed after running apt --fix-broken install. This is the second time this has happened. The only extras that I have installed is the proprietary Nvidia driver V=460. I have also installed the Mate terminal and a Yaru theme. When I try to boot Debian, I get the message: `Enter runlevel`. Here is a picture of the screen:

[image]

The first time this happened I did a reinstall, but if there is some method of recovery I would prefer that.

Comment: What if you enter a runlevel, like 5 (graphical boot) or 2 (text terminal only)? I guess your "apt --fix-broken" has removed some essential packages. If you are familiar enough with apt, entering a runlevel may allow you to boot, inspect the situation and reinstall them manually. If you are not, I'm afraid you should go through a complete reinstall.

Comment: @xhienne I tried that after posting the question. It doesn’t do anything after entering a runlevel except ask for the runlevel again.

Comment: Not even runlevel 2? Sad. But are you sure your `apt` command did not throw any errors? Usually you have a chance to fix problems before you reboot.

Comment: Debian (as most other distributions) moved to systemd. Here it's booting with sysv init. It's quite possible you are missing required files for proper sysv init operations, like for example /etc/inittab. This doesn't come by default. Is there a reason sysv init is booting instead of systemd? This could be related to what you were trying to fix with apt --fix-broken (which itself should not happen unless something weird was done, or maybe simply nvidia's driver caused the crash).

Comment: @Philippos After running apt --fix-broken the screen (GUI) completely locked up. I had to turn the computer power off to reboot.

Comment: If something like this ever happens again (I don't hope so), you can try to switch to a text screen with ctrl+alt+F1 to fix things and don't try to reboot a broken system.

Comment: @A.B inittab was missing. I replaced it with runlevel 3. I am still crashed. I will probably reinstall debian later but this is the second time the same problem occurred. I also believe the Nvidia driver may have something to do with it because it was an "almost" fresh Debian installation.

Comment: @Philippos Good to know